# How to create a static mapping but leave the rest of the fields as dynamic?

Tags: elasticsearch

When I'm importing my JSON data into Elasticsearch, one of the fields I have is a price field but in the JSON document it is represented as a string. I was wondering if it is possible to only set a static mapping for this field and leave the rest of the fields to be dynamically mapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default dynamic field mapping is enabled. So when a document being indexed have a field not present in mapping elasticsearch automatically update the mapping. Any field already in the mapping are used as is. So you need to add the property for `price` field and create index as below:

```
PUT myindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "price": {
          "type": "float"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above ensures that price field is always index by a float value. Any other fields in the document will be used to dynamically add fields to the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can create mapping for that field only and leave all other fields. When first document hit the elasticsearch mapping will be created for rest of the fields automatically.